minmax() function on css doesn't correctly work


body{
    width:100%;
}


.parent{
    background: red;
    padding:10px;
    
    
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(300px, auto));
    
    row-gap: 10px ;
    column-gap: 5px;
    width:100%;

}

.parent div{
    background: gold;
    width: 100%;

}

.parent .item1{
    background:rgb(88, 88, 237);
}

.parent .item2{
    background:rgb(204, 130, 165);
    
}

.parent .item3{
    background:rgb(111, 229, 107);
   
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-grid.css">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">

   <div class="item1">item1</div>
   <div class="item2">item2</div>
   <div class="item3">item3</div>
   <div class="item4">item4</div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>



i want to create a responsive form, but when i stretch the browser, the elements inside the form or the inputs dont take all the width of the form although i used this line code :
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(300px, auto));

the results i get by using the code above is similar to the results i get using the code below :
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,300px); 

ps: i already checked my code lines and compare them with codes found on youtube channels, there is no mistake in it and used also two different browsers
i tried the code lines below :
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(300px, auto));

i expected to get a responsive form and the inputs inside of it will take all the width but they dont
i'm getting a responsive form but the width of the inputs is not changing

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Without seeing the relevant HTML and its CSS I can’t be sure, but are you certain the width of your elements is more than 300px?

To make sure all horizontal space is used by the 4 items, try using auto-fit and 1fr (rather than auto) to specify the max size of a column.


body {
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, auto));
  row-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent div {
  background: gold;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent .item1 {
  background: rgb(88, 88, 237);
}

.parent .item2 {
  background: rgb(204, 130, 165);
}

.parent .item3 {
  background: rgb(111, 229, 107);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-grid.css">
  <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">

    <div class="item1">item1</div>
    <div class="item2">item2</div>
    <div class="item3">item3</div>
    <div class="item4">item4</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




It worked with both  auto-fit + 1fr  and auto-fit + auto
